# Using Firebase Authentication with PHP backend

Tags: laravel, firebase

We are building a firebase mobile app and need to put some payment (paypal) logic on a custom PHP backend (Laravel).
The question is what is the best solution to do authentication on the PHP side?
Currently we are thing in using API-Key library like https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard

Is there any better solution?